# Irrational numbers and Borel Sets

Tags: calculus, probability

Is the set of all irrational numbers in [0; 1] a Borel set? If yes,
what is its Lebesgue measure? I have been trying to answer this for a long time now. I know that the set of rational numbers is infinitely countable but I am having trouble with the proof of this question. I am not necessarily looking for an answer just confirmation that I am doing the correct thing.

I have already tried the following: The set of rationals is countable between 0 and 1 and is therefore a Borel Set. Since it is countable its lebesgue measure is 0

Comment: Your question would be better if you included some of the things you have tried when you were thinking about the problem. That would help others give more focused answers.

Answer (score 14):

The set of all rational numbers in $[0,1]$ is countable and hence a Borel set. Therefore, also its complement is a Borel set.

The Lebesgue measure of $[0,1]$ is $1$, the lebesgue measure of all rational numbers in $[0,1]$ is $0$ since it is countable. Therefore,...

Answer (score 0):

If you have thought about this, then I am sure you have the ability to answer it already! First, is the set of rationals a Borel set? What is the Lebesgue measure of the set of rationals?

Comment: The set of rationals is a Borel set, so its complement is also a Borel set, correct? The lebesgue measure of the rationals in (0,1) is 0 so the lebesgue measure for the irrationals is also O, correct?

Comment: Could you explain your reasoning in the second sentence of your comment?