# What is the lebesgue measure of irrational numbers between 0 and 1

Tags: calculus, probability

What is the lebesgue measure of irrational numbers between 0 and 1. This is a Borel set. I have figured out the following: The set of rational numbers is a Borel set so therefore the complement of the rational numbers, the irrational numbers, is also a Borel Set. I am having real trouble figuring out the Lebesgue measure. Please help!! I am not necessarily looking for an answer just guidance as to how I find the answer. I am fairly new to this level of math so any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the measure of $\mathbb Q$? Do you know that?

Comment: $1-\mu(\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1])$.

Comment: The solution is given in an answer to [your last question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/527061/39599).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: What is the measure of the set of rational numbers?  Is this set countable?